# How to install pythoncard?

Tags: 13.10, python, python-2.7

I am currently running ubuntu 13.10.I want to download pythoncard for python2.7.6.I also have anaconda1.8.0.So whenever i start python in my terminator or terminal,it starts along with anaconda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package python-pythoncard is in the universe repository, so a simple:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pythoncard
```

will work. Alternatively, open the Software Center and search for *pythoncard*.

Comment: This looks like an answer to me! (Comments are used to ask for clarifications and may be deleted.)

Comment: yeah,filmm is right.But thanks for your answer,Keba.

Comment: @saisanjeev: So, did it work out? Perhaps you should either mark the answer as correct or edit your question and state that this does not work because of …

Comment: @saisanjeev: If you anaccept an answer it might be an idea to tell us whether you still have a problem here.